# jQuery Response Parsin

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery response is of the following type. Please help me parse this to get individual element and its properties.

```
var data = {
  "ABC": { 
    "ID": 80668, 
    "RSSD": 166803, 
    "Title": "Vice President, Consumer Loans" 
  }, 
  "DEF": { 
    "ID": 80669, 
    "RSSD": 166803, 
    "Title": "President"
  }
}
```

Here I want to know how can I get values `ABC` from this above variable and also value of ID inside it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

`data.ABC`, `data.ABC.ID`, `data.DEF.Title`, etc.

or

`data['ABC']`, `data['ABC']['ID']`, `data['DEF']['Title']`, etc.